# Does extension return new instance each time

Tags: swift, memory, foundation, swift-extensions

Consider this case, a variable declared in an `extension`, like this.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var apiClient: APIClient {
        return APIClientImplementation()
    }
}
```

Does this extension return a new instance each time i call it from a different `UIViewController`, if so how this affects the memory ?

If not could this cause a problem, that i am getting the same instance for all the `UIViewController`'s that i am using this instance in, and as you can tell its an `APIClient` instance that is used to be injected into another instance of a `GateWay` class, can this lead to a problem in the future ?

> **Note**: `GateWay` class is class instance that i am using to execute API requests, each chunk of services has its own gateway.

I know i can use protocol to apply rules on the desired `UIViewController` to create instance each time.

What i am trying to achieve is to write less code with less problems in the future, and remove unnecessary chunks of code.

Comment: Although I am unable the understand the question, but basically `apiClient` *does* returns a new instance each time... By default it should get deallocated when the view controller gets deallocated.

Comment: So no memory hustle at any point or crashes, since this instance could be taken to a background thread for work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, everytime you access `apiClient` from any `viewController`, a new instance of `APIClient` will be returned.

As `apiClient` variable is `get only` so this itself can not cause any memory issues.

Comment: so i can work with it in background threads with no problems what so ever ?

Comment: As it looks this is not going to do anything with UI so yes, it should be able to work in background without any issue. But without understanding all the use cases, it's difficult to say it won't create any issue ever.